# Undefined method `to_date' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I tried to put a try method for fixing the error,but it won't still want it to work out.

If I wasn't specific enough, please let me know.

How to fix this error?

Comment: Sorry for not being specific about it.  The "to_date" method is being undefined. and i wonder how to fix it. i tried applying "try" but it still doesn't work cause the "beginning_of_day" ,method is still undefined and it goes on and on.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear - you're calling `nil.to_date`. You'll have to investigate every call to `to_date` and check whether the object is `nil`. At first glance, it looks like `params[:date]` is the culprit.

Comment: In  this case it means `params[:date]` is `nil`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you see a message saying "Undefined method 'foo' for nil:NilClass" it means that you are calling the method "foo" on an object whose value is nil.  Like everything in Ruby, "nil" is an object, and it's class is NilClass - that's what the message means.

In this case, the object in question is `params[:date]`, since that is what you are calling the `.to_date` method on.  `params` is a Hash (well, a hash-like object at least), and with a hash, if you call a key on it and it doesn't have that key, it returns `nil`.

So, your problem is that you are expecting `params[:date]` to have something in it, and it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should handle situations when the parameter :date hasn't been given. Maybe use a default value like this:

```
if params.has_key?(:date) 
  date = DateTime.parse(params[:date])
else 
  date = DateTime.now
end
po_id = CardApplicationTrack.where(
  :batched_for_payment => true, 
  :admin_user_id => params[:admin_user_id].to_i, 
  :created_at => 
    date.beginning_of_day ..
    date.end_of_day
).map { |cat| cat.processing_order_id }
```

Or tell the user that you didn't enter a date if params[:date] is missing.

Comment: I put this condition   if params[:date].present?  and now it's working and yes, the page is empty for the moment since there's no data on it.   Thank you very much for all y'all answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `.try` method, try following.

```
date = params[:date].try(:to_date) || DateTime.now

po_id = CardApplicationTrack.where(
  batched_for_payment: true, 
  admin_user_id: params[:admin_user_id].to_i, 
  created_at: date.beginning_of_day..date.end_of_day
).pluck(:processing_order_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not throw error.

params[:date].try(:to_date).try(:end_of_day)